# Using custom local domain with Docker

Tags: docker

I am running Docker using **Docker Desktop** on **Windows**.

I would like to set-up a simple server.

I run it using:

```
$ docker run -di -p 1234:80 yahya/example-server
```

This works as expected and runs fine on `localhost:1234`.

However, I want to give it's own local domain name (e.g. `api.example.test`), which should only be accessible locally.

Normally for a VM setup I would edit the Windows `hosts` file, get the IP address of the VM (let's say it's `192.168.90.90`) and add something like the following:

```
192.168.90.90 api.example.test
```

How would I do something similar in Docker.

I know you can enter an ip address for port forwarding, but if I enter any local IP I get the following error:

```
$ docker run -di -p 192.168.90.90:1234:80 yahya/example-server
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 192.168.90.90:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 192.168.90.90:80: can't bind on the specified endpoint.
```

However, it does work for `10.0.0.7` for some reason (I found this IP automatically added in the hosts file after installing Docker Desktop).

```
$ docker run -di -p 10.0.0.7:1234:80 yahya/example-server
```

This essentially solves the issue, but would become an issue again if I have more than 1 project.

Is there a way I can use another local IP address (preferably without a nginx proxy)?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no simple way to do this without some kind of reverse-proxy.

In my dev environment I use [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) and [dnscrypt-proxy](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy) to achieve automatic `*.test` domain names for multiple projects at same time

First, start Traefik proxy on ports 80 and 433, example `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
---
networks:
  traefik:
    name: traefik

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.8.3
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      TRAEFIK_API: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_http: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_http_ADDRESS: :80
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_https: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_https_ADDRESS: :443
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_https_HTTP_TLS: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_GLOBAL_CHECKNEWVERSION: 'false'
      TRAEFIK_GLOBAL_SENDANONYMOUSUSAGE: 'false'
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_EXPOSEDBYDEFAULT: 'false'
```

Then, attach your service to `traefik` network, and set labels for routing (see [Traefik & Docker](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/)). Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
---
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

services:
  example:
    image: yahya/example-server
    restart: always
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.docker.network: traefik
      traefik.http.routers.example.rule: Host(`example.test`)
      traefik.http.services.example.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
    networks:
      - traefik
```

Finally, add to `hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.test
```

Instead of manually adding all future domains to `hosts`, you can setup local DNS resolver. I prefer to use [cloaking](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Cloaking) feature of [dnscrypt-proxy](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy) for this.

You can install it using [Installation instructions](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation#os-specific-instructions), then uncomment following line in `dnscrypt-proxy.toml`:

```
cloaking_rules = 'cloaking-rules.txt'
```

and add to `cloaking-rules.txt`:

```
*.test 127.0.0.1
```

finally, setup your network connection to use `127.0.0.1` as DNS resolver